# AspNetIdentity login fails on Azure - Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-identity, connection-string, usermanager

**DISCLAIMER** : Even if this error has been asked in a lot of topics before, I didn't find an anwser to my question ; please feel free to answer it before flagging as duplicate, 'coz it's not a duplicate :-)

---

I use [Identity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/) in an ASP.NET MVC5 Database first project.

I've made a lot of changes in my solution recently, including adding a column in `AspNetUsers` table. I've already done that a dozen of times, everything works fine.

**When I test my solution with all the new changes in localhost, everything works perfectly, including login**.

Then, I published my code and DB changes on my PreProd environment, hosted on Azure (for the record)

New changes are OK, however, when I try to login into my project, it fails and I have the following error in my logs :

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Problem occurs in `Login` HttpPost method, only while invoking `UserManager`

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    try
    {
        //Just to proove I can access to my DB
        var businessLayer = new businessLayer();
        var dataFromDB = businessLayer.GetDataFromMyDB();
        logger.Info(dataFromDB ); //dataFromDB is the expected value from my DB

        logger.Info("Will call UserManager");
        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email.Trim());  // <- Fails here in PreProd only
        logger.Info(I never go here (in PreProd only)");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         //Fails here in PreProd only with above error message
         logger.Error(ex, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In localhost everything is fine, in preprod (hosted in Azure) it fails while calling `UserManager.FindByEmailAsync`

Here is my ConnectionString in localhost

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDataModel.csdl|res://*/MyDataModel.ssdl|res://*/MyDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDBName3;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Here is my ConnectionString for Azure Preprod

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDataModel.csdl|res://*/MyDataModel.ssdl|res://*/MyDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=tcp:xxxazure.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDbName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=MyUserID;Password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

*When I use the PreProd connection string from VisualStudio in Release mode, there's no problem at all and I can log in ( ?!?! )*
So it seems the problem is from the PreProd environment itself, isn't it ?

What I've tried so far :

- Copy/Paste the connection string in web.config directly in my FTP
- Try changing the `&quot;` by `'`
- Try remove everything in the connection string except required elements (User ID, Password..)
- [Google my problem](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Format%20of%20the%20initialization%20string%20does%20not%20conform%20to%20specification%20starting%20at%20index%200.), click on every link on the first page, but still have my problem
- Randomly change `Integrated Security` and other bool value in connection string
- Turn 7 times on my chair while whispering a voodoo incantation

Can anyone tell me :

- Why it fails only in PreProd while hosted on Azure
- How can I correct it ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Just few things to tryout:

If you have connection string like below in your code

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TestDB.csdl|res://*/TestDB.ssdl|res://*/TestDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=XXXXXXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=YourDB;User ID=YourUser;Password=XXXXXX&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Add this in azure portal in application settings:

```
Name Column => Entities

Value Column => metadata=res://*/TestDB.csdl|res://*/TestDB.ssdl|res://*/TestDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=XXXXXXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=YourDB;User ID=YourUser;Password=XXXXXX" 

"Custom" - In the drop selection box
```

[image]

Please make sure to change the " to " in azure portal.

To convert from a "normal" connection string to one that is accepted by EF:

1) The connection string type in the application settings has to be "other" not "SQL Azure"

2) The connection string value automatically replaces anything published in web.config

Try these options and see if it works.